# Javascript Decryption of hex code key and data in TRipleDes

Tags: javascript, encryption, utf-8, hex, encode

Am having a password and pin as hex codes which is generated from JAVA. I need to decrypt this in javascript client side. Help me to resolve this.

First i have generated a public and private key using node forge in client side.

```
var keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(512);
forge.pki.publicKeyToPem(keys.publicKey)
```

Then i have sent that public key to a service. It returned an encrypted key and an encrypted data. To decrypt the data, first i need to decrypt the key which i got from the service.

```
var decrypted= keys.privateKey.decrypt(forge.util.decode64("M+v0Su2bzQPp20yvsVcySP+Z+iK2egV6hKJ6UNIubVPkVoOilhn+ywXDdm8LOW/37UimsB6reRm+XHR8uHZHJQ=="));
decrypted = forge.utils.bytesToHex(decrypted);
```

I have got the decrypted key now.

```
decrypted key - da019e4c07132376543b235e7f8a432c
```

Now i need to decrypt the data using this key with tripleDES algorithm. In service side **DESede/ECB/NOPadding** algorithm was used.

```
Data to be decrypted Hex- 717AAE5F33D06EFA
output should be 62261FFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and the [help] before posting again.  Voting to close.

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: Still far too broad.  Include what you've tried and how the ciphertext is produced.

Comment: please check now if its understandable